# How to fit a negative binomial, normal, and poisson density function on the same ggplot2 (R) but scaled to the count data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, distribution, data-fitting

I have some count data. I want to plot histogram with the count data and add the negative binomial, normal, and Poisson density function but fit the functions to the count data.

I tried following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661852/adding-a-density-line-to-a-histogram-with-count-data-in-ggplot2) but (a) I have trouble fitting the negative binomial and poisson functions (b) No where close to scaling it to the count data level (c) Dont know how to fit all three on same graph with legends for each line (d) Also, how can I get basic stats of each fit? for example, the neg binomial fit will generate a parameter k. How can I get that to appear on the plot

```
set.seed(111)
counts <- rbinom(500,100,0.1) 
df <- data.frame(counts)

ggplot(df, aes(x = counts)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  stat_function(fun=dnorm,args=fitdistr(df$counts,"normal")$estimate)

ggplot(df, aes(x = counts)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  stat_function(fun=poisson,args=fitdistr(df$counts,"poisson")$estimate)

ggplot(df, aes(x = counts)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  stat_function(fun=dnbinom,args=fitdistr(df$counts,"dnbinom")$estimate)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few issues, first `"dnbinom"` is not a valid distribution for `MASS::fitdistr`. Secondly, `MASS::fitdistr` wasn't able to get a fit with the default method, so we can use `method = "SANN"`. Thirdly, `stat_function` tries to evaluate `dnbinom` at non-integer values unless you tell it otherwise, which doesn't work.

Getting the parameters to show in the legend is a little tricky, because you'll have to estimate them outside of the `ggplot` call. I was lazy and used `purrr::map2`, but you could use some base R functions to do the same thing.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
norm.params <- fitdistr(df$counts,"normal")$estimate
poisson.params <- fitdistr(df$counts,"poisson")$estimate
negbinom.params <- fitdistr(df$counts,"negative binomial", method = "SANN")$estimate

dist.params <- map(list(Normal = norm.params,Poisson = poisson.params,`Negative Binomial` = negbinom.params),
    ~ map2(names(.),.,~ paste0(.x," = ",round(.y,2))) %>% unlist %>% paste0(.,collapse = ", ")) %>% 
    map2_chr(names(.),., ~ paste(.x,.y,sep=":\n"))
```

Finally, if we want to scale by counts, as found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27662375/13095326), we just define anonymous functions.

```
mybinwidth = 1
ggplot(df, aes(x = counts)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count..),colour = "black", fill = "white", binwidth = mybinwidth) +
  stat_function(aes(color = "black"),fun=function(x,mean,sd) mybinwidth * nrow(df) * dnorm(x,mean, sd),
                args=fitdistr(df$counts,"normal")$estimate) +
  stat_function(aes(color = "blue"),fun=function(x,lambda) mybinwidth * nrow(df) * dpois(x,lambda), 
                args=fitdistr(df$counts,"poisson")$estimate,
                xlim=c(1,20), n=20) + 
  stat_function(aes(color = "orange"),fun=function(x,size, mu) mybinwidth * nrow(df) * dnbinom(x,size = size, mu = mu),
                args=fitdistr(df$counts,"negative binomial", method="SANN")$estimate,
                xlim=c(1,20),n=20) + 
  scale_color_manual("Distribution", values=c(black="black",blue="blue",orange="orange"),
                     labels=dist.params)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is quite helpful. Would it be be possible to scale the density to original frequency like in the example post? I'm still struggling with that. Also, for the negative binom distribution I get an error saying there is not method called "SAMM"..shows me a "SANN" option. The resultant plot params are different. Any idea why?

Comment: "SAMM" was a typo on my part. I also added the scaling function.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for the Poisson density.

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = counts)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),colour = "black", fill = "white", bins=20) +
  stat_function(fun=dpois, args=fitdistr(df$counts,"poisson")$estimate, 
                xlim=c(0,19), n=20, size=1) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

And here is a solution for the negative binomial.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = counts)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),colour = "black", fill = "white", bins=20) +
  stat_function(fun=dnbinom, 
                args=fitdistr(df$counts,"negative binomial", method="SANN")$estimate, 
                xlim=c(0,19), n=20, size=1) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]